# How can i use the value of the number without the '.' which is generated by thousands_sep?

Tags: php

As you can see I have the `thousands_sep` with a dot, and `"Summe"` as the last column obv. is trying to calculate the sum of the `rows` but it uses `1556€` as `1.556€` thats why i get `234€` instead of `1.788`

[image: As u can see i have the thousands_sep with a dot, and "Summe" as the last column obv. is trying to calculate the sum of the rows but it uses 1556€ as 1.556€ thats why i get 234€ instead of 1.788]

```
  for ( $a = 0; $a < $i; $a++){

            $sum += $tabledata[$a]['value'];
        }
        $ajaxreturn['beschriftungen'] = $beschriftungen;
        $ajaxreturn['chartData'] = $chartdata;
        $ajaxreturn['tablehead'] = $tablehead;
        $tabledata[(count($tabledata))]= array('category'=>"Summe",'value' => number_format($sum, 0, ',', '.').'&euro;', 'id' => $i);
```

I tried to change many things but what i need is that the input is `"converted"` to a number without the '.'

```
                $chartdata[] = array('date' => $iddate, 'value' => round($zeile['summe']), 'id' => $i);
                $tabledata[] = array('category' => $beschriftung, 'value' => number_format($zeile['summe'], 0, '', '.').'&euro;', 'id' => $i);
```

Comment: Where does tabledata come from

Comment: It is an array which is filled above with data from a mysqldatabase

Comment: So you've also stored this incorrectly in your database as 'one point five five six' and you need to go back and fix *that* code.

Comment: I edited my source code, so maybe you can understand what i mean now.

Comment: Why have you tagged this with as javascript and jquery? Your code appears to be all php, is that correct?

Comment: You should track the summe inside the query loop, rather than make a second loop afterwards that tries to sum the formatted numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to calculate the sum from the formatted number array (`$tabledata`), you should calculate the sum alongside the `tabledata`, like:

```
$beschriftungen[$iddate] = $beschriftung;
$chartdata[] = array('date' => $iddate, 'value' => round($zeile['summe']), 'id' => $i);
$tabledata[] = array('category' => $beschriftung, 'value' => number_format($zeile['summe'], 0, '', '.').'&euro;', 'id' => $i);

$sum += $zeile['summe'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace('.', '', $value);` or even better, `preg_replace('/\D/', '', $value)`. `preg_replace` will remove also the currency symbol and possible spaces.